# A question regarding vector spaces with partial order

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lattice-orders, vector-lattices

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbf{N}}$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}$
Let $X=(X,\leq)$ be a [Riesz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space) (a lattice which is also an [ordered vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space) over $\R$). Define $X^+=\{x\in X\colon x\ge 0\}$. Are the following statements equivalent?

1. For all $x$ in $X^+$, $\inf \{ \frac{1}{n}\cdot x\colon n\in\N \} = 0$.
2. If $x,y\in X^+$ and $n\cdot x\leq y$ for all $n\in \N$, then $x=0$.
3. For all $x,y\in X^+$ with $x\neq 0$ the set $\{ \lambda\in \R\colon \lambda x \leq y \}$ has a largest element.

Comment: At least, 1. implies 2., because $\inf \frac 1ny=0$. What makes you think these statements are equivalent? a particular example?